# Bi directional data flow with Dat

Tags: node.js, dat-protocol, dat-project

I have a folder that turned into a Dat with

```
$ dat share
```

Then in a different machine, I've access to it like (from node script)

```
const Dat = require('util').promisify(require('dat-node'))

dat = await Dat(DAT_FOLDER, { key })
dat.joinNetwork()
```

Everything is fine until now, The original machine tells me there is a new connection, so we are good. From here I don't know how to proceed. I want to write data from the peer machine to the original one. First, I though that it will be enough to make it writable, so I did like this

```
// got secretKey some how
if (typeof secretKey === 'string') secretKey = Buffer.from(secretKey, 'hex')
dat.archive.metadata._storage.secretKey.write(0, secretKey, done)
```

But writing to the archive only writes on my cloned Dat, how to *push* back to the original Dat? Is that even posible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dat is currently single-writer, which means that only one device can make changes.

Having multiple "writers" to a Dat is known as Multiwriter. That's a feature which is currently being developed for Dat, and should be rolled out later this year or early 2019.

Comment: Oh! that's the multiwriter thing, I hear it a lot but I thought it was something else. Good to know, thanks!